# Given an array of numbers, is it possible to split them into equal lengths?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, number-theory

I'm looking for a solution as to how we can make sure every number has a destination bucket - doesn't matter where it lands.

For example - I have an array of numbers - not necessarily sorted
[1,3,5,10,15,20]

I have two buckets - lets say [40, 20]
I can split them up like this
40 - [15, 20, 5]
20 - [1, 3, 10]

In conclusion - given an array of numbers [1, 2, .. n]
Find a way to group these up into buckets that has a total of n,

I've tried multiple solutions but am not able to find a concrete solution. Highly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: _"group these up into buckets that has a total of n"_. Where have you mentioned any "totalling" in your examples?

Comment: This sounds like it could be solved by a greedy algorithm, where you can sort the array to have the largest numbers first. Then, sort the buckets to have the largest capacities first. Fill each bucket until the next biggest number would overflow it, and in that case just move onto the next bucket.

Comment: You always get the numbers from 1 to n as input? Because this was not the case in your example.

Comment: Is it correct that you can put as many numbers in a bucket as long as the sum does not exceed the capacity?

Comment: If your buckets have a fixed capacity, and your input array are arbitrary numbers, this is NP-hard -- it's essentially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem. Given the two buckets of size A and B, with the sum of the input being S, the decision problem is "is there a subset of the numbers which sum to something between S-B and A."